# Cluster Terminated with errorsEMR service role arn:aws:iam::xyz:role/EMR_DefaultRole is invalid

Tags: java, amazon-emr

I am defining default role like

```
request.setServiceRole("EMR_DefaultRole");
request.setJobFlowRole("EMR_EC2_DefaultRole");
```

and getting the error:

> EMR service role arn:aws:iam::xyz:role/EMR_DefaultRole is invalid

I don't have permission to create roles. Why am i getting errors on default?